# Prove the existence a solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

- Suppose that $\,\mathrm{f}:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is continuously differentiable.
- Suppose that for some $R > 0$ one
  has: $\,\mathrm{f}\left(x\right) x < 0$ for all $x\in\partial B_R$, where $B_{R}$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which its center is the origin and radius $R$.
- Prove that for any $x_{0} \in B_{R}$ there is a solution valid for all
  $t > 0$ of the following the problem: 
  $$
  x' = \,\mathrm{f}\left(x\right)\,,\quad x\left(0\right) = x_{0}.
  $$

Here is what I am trying: using the condition of $\,\mathrm{f}$ on the compact set $B_{R} \cup \partial B_{R}$, we could achieve the Lipschitz condition so the problem have a solution.

However, I don't know what steps I should continue. 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The fundamental fact is the following:  SInce $f(x)\cdot x< 0$ on $\partial B$, you have that such inequaility holds in a neighborhood of $\partial B$ too: this means that when you are approaching the boundary of $B$, the velocity vector field points to the interior of the ball. This implies that your solution is bounded to stay in the ball, and thus, by classical ODE theory, must live forever.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuously differentiable, then it's derivative is bounded on the union of $B_R$ and $\partial B_R$, which is compact. This bound can serve as the Lipschitz constant for $f$ on the compact ball. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @MattiaFogagnolo: could you please explain more? Thank you very much. In fact, I understand about the meaning of phenomenon. But I cannot explain why it is happen. Could you also provide me the theorem which you mentioned as classical ODE?

Comment: You see that $f(x)$ gives you the velocity in the position $x$, right? (I use a physical language because I think it helps to visualize). So, remember what geometrical meaning has scalar product, and convince yourself that, in a neighborhood of the boundary of the ball, such velocity must point to the interior. So, any time your solution approaches the boundary, it is rejected to the interior, so it is bounded, so it has to live forever. (This last part is actually a theorem, I can look for a reference if you don't know it)

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you also provide me a reference?

Comment: Look here: http://www.math.unipd.it/~monti/ED2/PC13GiugnoFinale.pdf  , page 22: Theorem 2.6.3: actually, since you can't escape the ball, your solution can't approach $+ \infty$, and so, it has to live for all times.

Comment: @MattiaFogagnolo: I really appreciate your help. That's really good reference.